# Lubutu crashes and failed

Tags: lubuntu, crash

I downloaded the ISO file for Lubuntu, a lightweight version of Ubuntu I think, successfully installed on my oldie laptop inherited from my Grandpa and I've been  using it for a while with no issues. However, for the past three days, it just goes off and and print out some kind of gibberish commands:

[image]

Edit:

```
genius@GeniusDPhil-hp250g1notebookpc:~/Projects/alx-stuffs/alx-higher_level_programming/0x06-python-classes$ chmod +x 3-square.py 
chmod: changing permissions of '3-square.py': Read-only file system
genius@GeniusDPhil-hp250g1notebookpc:~/Projects/alx-stuffs/alx-higher_level_programming/0x06-python-classes$ git push
error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/main': cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/main': Unable to create '/home/genius/Projects/alx-stuffs/alx-higher_level_programming/.git/refs/remotes/origin/main.lock': Read-only file system
Everything up-to-date
genius@GeniusDPhil-hp250g1notebookpc:~/Projects/alx-stuffs/alx-higher_level_programming/0x06-python-classes$ sudo                         
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-ABkNnS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-ABkNnS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user]
            [-u user] [command [arg ...]]
usage: sudo [-ABbEHkNnPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-D
            directory] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-R
            directory] [-T timeout] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i | -s]
            [command [arg ...]]
usage: sudo -e [-ABkNnS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-D directory]
            [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-R directory] [-T
            timeout] [-u user] file ...
genius@GeniusDPhil-hp250g1notebookpc:~/Projects/alx-stuffs/alx-higher_level_programming/0x06-python-classes$ su                           
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
genius@GeniusDPhil-hp250g1notebookpc:~/Projects/alx-stuffs/alx-higher_level_programming/0x06-python-classes$ su                           
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
genius@GeniusDPhil-hp250g1notebookpc:~/Projects/alx-stuffs/alx-higher_level_programming/0x06-python-classes$
```

Now i can't even do anything.

Comment: Try another harddrive. The filesystem shows errors.

Comment: Could be the drive (install smartmontools package and run sudo smartctl -a /dev/<sda>  and post the text output in your origina posting. (or whatever sd? your system has)).  Could be the filesystem (improper shutdown, etc. which an offline fsck might fix.

Comment: All I see are errors on device sda5. You've provided no release detail, but I'd too suggest you perform checks on your hardware (SMART to check drive health; just as you do with windows/apple etc) and perform those checks from *live* media as it'll be easier if SDA isn't in-use. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools   If it's due to power loss (*or user created by holding power button to force shutdown*) it'll be a *logical* error that `fsck` or file-system checks will fix; but what you are seeing if no power-loss, can be failing hardware warning sign: drive, psu, ram..